# Problem with Xbox Live Split screen for COD ghosts

Tags: xbox-360

I have this problem where I'm signed into Xbox Live and no one else is.

I go to the Xbox Live screen in multiplayer to find match and it says press A for split screen and when I click on guest it says **please use a valid membership.**

Comment: Do you have gold membership, and are you trying to search with the second(guest player)?

Answer (score 2):

You most likely need to have an Xbox Live account for each player that you wish to have play online. At least one of these accounts, possibly both, must be Gold. While you may be able to play locally with a Guest account, this won't work for online play.

Comment: 1 up, however, a guest should work for online play.

Comment: From memory a guest account works for Black Ops I & II, however it has never worked for Infinity Ward games. From recent experience, we couldn't play Ghosts **online** without two PSN accounts, but local play was okay with just a guest.

Comment: Gold is a must.